# Vanishing of $H^*(f^{-1}[0,c], f^{-1}(0))$ for small $c$, and $f\in C^0(X, [0,+\infty))$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory, cohomology

Let $X$ be a topological space and consider a continuous function $f:X\to [0,+\infty)$. For $c\geq 0$ set $X_c := f^{-1} ([0,c])$.
Furthermore, suppose that $X_0 \neq \emptyset$ and $f$ is proper.

**Motivating example**
If $X$ is a closed manifold and $f$ is smooth and $0$ is a regular value, then $X_0$ is a smooth submanifold and $X_c\cong X_0\times [0,1]$ when $c$ is small enough.  Consequently, the cohomology of the pair $H^*(X_c, X_0)\simeq (0)$.
If $X$ is a closed  manifold and $f$ is smooth  (without the assumption of $0$ being a regular value)the same still holds even if $X_0$ now can have singularities, indeed we can consider the flow of the normalized gradient of $f$,  $\Phi:X\times \mathbb{R}\to X$ which gives a retraction of $X_c$ onto $X_0$.

What can be said in the general case?

> Is it still true that there for all $c$ sufficiently small  $H^*(X_c, X_0) \simeq (0)$? Does it hold at least when $X$ is a topological manifold?

Comment: Don't you want $f$ proper maybe? Otherwise $f(x) = 1/x$ from $\mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R^+$ seems to give a counter-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this degree of generality I don't think you can say anything. Here are two pathological examples:

- If X is the [Hawaiian earring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring) and $f(x,y) = x$, then for any $c>0$, $f^{-1}([0,c])$ retracts on a copy of the Hawaiian earring (hence has very large $H^1$).
- If X is $\mathbb R^2$ and
  $f(x,y) = e^{\frac{-1}{x^2+y^2}}h(x^2+y^2)$ where $h$ is a smooth positive bounded function on $\mathbb R_{>0}$ that oscillates very fast near $0$, then there are arbitrary small values $c$ such that $f^{-1}([0,c])$ has small will have a connected component which is an annulus (hence has non-zero $H^1$). Choosing $h$ carefully enough, you can even arrange so that this is true for all $c$.